# docker login on gitlab-ci error: dial tcp: lookup on 127.0.0.53:53: no such host

Tags: .net, docker, gitlab, nexus, runner

I trying to set up a private code repository and ci/cd with Gitlab, Gitlab runner, SonarQube and Nexus. Both my containers are in same networks, m y runner already can send data to sonarqube and publish packages to nexus nuget hosted. Now, i'm trying to publish a docker image to nexus docker -hosted from my gitlab pipeline. My nexus container has a port mapped on 8083 and a docker hosted repository configured.

Heres my runner config.toml:

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0
shutdown_timeout = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "dotnet"
  url = "http://gitlab.mynetwork.com"
  id = 1
  token = "glrt-uoued6DwvHb7VK6n9oRb"
  token_obtained_at = 2023-06-21T22:34:27Z
  token_expires_at = 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.cache]
    MaxUploadedArchiveSize = 0
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk"
    privileged = true
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache", "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"]
    shm_size = 0
    network_mode = "mynetwork"
```

And my gitlab-ci.yml:

```
image: docker:stable

services:
- name: docker:dind
  command: ["--insecure-registry=nexus.mynetwork.com:8083"]

before_script:
  - docker info
  - docker login -u $NEXUS_USER -p $NEXUS_PASSWORD nexus.mynetwork.com:8083

stages:
  - publish

publish:
  stage: publish
  script:
    - docker build -t $IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_VERSION $DOCKERFILE
    - docker tag $IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_VERSION $NEXUS_URL/$NEXUS_REPOSITORY/$IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_VERSION
    - docker push nexus.mynetwork.com:8083/$NEXUS_REPOSITORY/$IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_VERSION
```

> Error response from daemon: Get "https://nexus.mynetwork.com:8083/v2/": dial tcp: lookup nexus.mynetwork.com on 127.0.0.53:53: no such host

I tested inside runner container the following command: `ping nexus.mynetwork.com` and it can reach it successfully.

Why only with command `docker login` thats happen? With commands `nuget push` and `sonarscanner end` my runner can connect with nexus nuget-hosted and sonarqube